# React Native: How to make Listview with with local images

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I made an album that looks sort of like this:

```
<ScrollView>   
  <Image1 
     <Text1>
        smth
     </Text1>    />

  <Image2
     <Text2>
        smthElse
     </Text2>    />' ... and so on 20 times.
```

I have 5 albums, which I access with tabs on top. 
The problem is that sometimes when I switch between the tabs, some images are blank and don't load. The images are all required like this:

```
source={require('../assets/Image1.png')}
```

I want them to be required from the app and not via uri.

I thought the problem is because of the memory and on weaker phones it's possible that they don't always load, because I use a ScrollView and it loads all the images at once. I read that a ListView quite solve my problem, but I can't figure out how to make a ListView that renders 20 specific images with a specific text for each one.

If anyone can give me some clues it would be much appreciated.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `<ListView>` You can require all the images on your **.js** file. On the top of your **.js** file you can do is

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Listview} from 'react-native'; //Import your other imports ofcourse

// Require all your images here
const image1 = require('../assets/Image1.png')
const image2 = require('../assets/Image2.png')

//.. And so on
export default class ClassName extends Component{
//...
}
```

Next is create an **array object** and add it to your constructor  on your **index.js** like so

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Listview} from 'react-native'; //Import your other imports ofcourse

// Require all your images here
const image1 = require('../assets/Image1.png')
const image2 = require('../assets/Image2.png')

var data = [{title:"You image title", image: image1}, {title:"Your Image title",image: image2}]

export default class ClassName extends Component{
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
     this.state = {
       dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
     };
  }
}
```

Next Create a **Row.js**

**Row.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, Platform, Image, View, Text } from 'react-native';
const Row = (props) => (
  <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}> //Don't forget this
    <Image source={props.image}>
      <Text>{props.title}</Text> 
    </Image>
  </View>
)

export default Row
```

Lastly Import your **Row.js** file on your **index.js** and add the `<ListView>` on your `render()`

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View,Listview} from 'react-native'; //Import your other imports ofcourse
import Row from './Row'; //If it's on the same folder

// Require all your images here
const image1 = require('../assets/Image1.png')
const image2 = require('../assets/Image2.png')

var data = [{title:"You image title", image: image1}, {title:"Your Image title",image: image2}]

export default class ClassName extends Component{
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
     this.state = {
       dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
     };
  }
  render(){
     <View>
       <ListView
         style={{flex:1}} //Don't forget this too
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} />}
       />
     </View>
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question how to use a ListView to render 20 images. We are using a [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) for rendering multiple photos. I will share the snippets below to get you started.

**SectionList**

```
<SectionList
    contentContainerStyle={styles.sectionListContainer}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    renderSectionHeader={this.renderHeader}
    sections={this.state.ImageData}
/>
```

**this.renderItem**

```
renderItem(data) {
    return (
        <View key={data.item.key} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.foodPhoto}
                    source={{ uri: `data:image/jpg;base64,${data.item.photo}`}}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )

}
```

To format the **this.state.ImageData** it took us a bit of fiddling to get the formatting/schema right for the SectionList. The format itself is documented at RN documentation. Hope that this helps!